# Convert string to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm creating some data as a string in a webservice and returning that string for use with jqPlot. My problem is that the jqPlot is expecting an object and im struggling to get my string into the correct format.

This working example is fine as the line1 variable is constructed as an object

```
var line1 = [['2007-02-18 00:00:00',4980],['2007-02-24 09:50:00',4230],['2007-05-20 00:00:00',5060]]
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
                    title: 'Test Plot',
                    title: 'Data with Dates',
                    axes: { xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer} },
                });
```

In my scenario a webservice is returning line one as a string:

```
line1 = "[['2007-02-18 00:00:00',4980],['2007-02-24 09:50:00',4230],['2007-05-20 00:00:00',5060]]"
```

How do I manipulate this string so I can use it as an array for jqPlot, as in the working example?

Comment: JSON can only exist in JavaScript in a string as well, as it is a textual exchange format. I think you mean you want to convert the string into a JavaScript array (I edited your question accordingly). Do you have control over the web service?

Comment: Just remove double quotes (") in your case and it should work, if you cannot do that use JSON parser from json.org or use eval function (not reliable)

Comment: Thanks for correcting the question @FelixKling. I do have control of the service although using `jQuery.parseJSON()` seems to be a workable solution.

Comment: @Fly_Trap: But the string is not JSON, strings must be in double quotes, i.e. `["2007-02-18 00:00:00",4980]`. If you fix this then yes, you can use that function and using JSON is appropriate in this situation. *Edit:* I just saw you already noticed that. I would still suggest you generate proper JSON on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery already anyway, why not throw it into [the utility function made especially for dealing with this problem](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)?

```
var json_string = "some_json_string",
    obj = $.parseJSON(json_string);
```

Comment: I tried this but initially ran into a problem with the single quotes: "Invalid JSON". So I ran `line1.replace(/'/g, '\"'))` to convert the single quotes to double quotes and that did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.parse()` will do it.  You'll need to shim it or use `eval` in browsers that don't support it.

```
if (window.JSON) {
    line1 = JSON.parse(line1);
}
else if (src === trustedSource && looksLikeJSON(line1)) {
    line1 = eval(line1);
}
```

[json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) is the recommended shim, it behaves just like the native `JSON` object.

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be `eval('line1=' + line1);` or (less confusing) `eval('object1=' + line1);`

Comment: @Jochem: whoops minor mistake there.  Yes, you need to assign the result from `eval`.  I kept the variable name the same because the OP used the same variable to represent the string and the original example array, with the latter omitting the `var` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If the target user agent has the `window.JSON` object defined then you can simply call:

```
var line1 = JSON.parse([your string from webservice]);
```

If the user agent does not natively support the JSON object then you will have to include the script which is featured here: [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate your String into a JavaScript object. That is what the [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) method is for.

`line1 = eval("[['2007-02-18 00:00:00',4980],['2007-02-24 09:50:00',4230],['2007-05-20 00:00:00',5060]]")`

Keep in mind that you might run into problems with special characters etc.

Answer (score 1):

With Vanilla JS, JSON.stringify and JSON.parse are used to manipulate data with JSON. 
May refer this [JavaScript With JSON](http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/working-with-javascript.php) and [JSON Example](http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/JSON-example.php).